# Get Image source from Image after uploading

Tags: c#, image, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am currently following walk through on how to upload an image from a phone's photo gallery [link here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/photo-picker) to allow users to upload an image to my application which they can set as their profile picture. I am able to get an image from the phone's gallery however when I try and save, I cannot retrieve the image source from the `xaml`.

Below is the `xaml` for the image and the button that the user clicks on to upload an image.

```
                <Button Text="Pick a Profile Image"
                        Clicked="OnPictureButton_Clicked"
                        Grid.Column="0"></Button>
                <Image Source="{Binding Employee.ProfilePicture}"
                        Grid.Column="1"
                        x:Name="profilePicture"
                        Grid.RowSpan="2"
                        WidthRequest="200"></Image>
```

Here is the corresponding c# code:

```
    private async void OnPictureButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        (sender as Button).IsEnabled = false;

        // _stream is a private global variable
        // Allow the user to view images on the phone
        _stream = await DependencyService.Get<IPhotoPickerService>().GetImageStreamASync();

        // If they select an image, set it as the source for profilePicture
        if (_stream != null)
        {
            profilePicture.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => _stream);
        }

        (sender as Button).IsEnabled = true;

    }

    private async void Clicked_EmployeeSaved(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var data = (EmployeeFull)BindingContext;
        var uploadedPicture = profilePicture.Source;    // Should be uploaded image

        // Testing how to get the source for the image (Can disregard for question)
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeStream(_stream);
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

        bitmap.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg, 100, ms);

        byte[] byteArray;

        byteArray = ms.ToArray();

    }
```

Now, I know that once the user selects an image from the gallery on their device, the stream closes and so I will be unable to access it later on in the code, like I have tried in the second function shown.

However, I am unable to retrieve the name of the image that I have selected to upload. On the screen, the user is able to see this image as I have set the selected image as the source for the `profilePicture` tag but when I try and get that source when the user clicks 'save', it shows an ImageSource` object, not a string which I expected.

Is there another way I can get the uploaded image's name?

Comment: you need to save a reference to the selected image when the user picks it and re-use that reference later.

Comment: @Jason I did see that. So save a reference to `memoryStream` and access it in the second method such as   `MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();` ` _stream.CopyTo(ms);`?

Comment: or save the byte[] from the stream in memory.  Or write it to a file.

Comment: @Jason And how would I retrieve the value in  the second function?

Comment: use a class level variable

Comment: Try to use some pattern like MVVM instead of doing everything in the code-behind. Sooner or later, this will become a problem or it will be hard to maintain/make change.

Comment: do you mean you want to get the image 's path ?

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT Essentially yes. I can preview the image, but I want to save it in the database. To do this I need the image's name however I cannot seem to get it in the code after the stream is shut.

Comment: @JamesS if you want to get the file name from the image source stream,i'm sorry to tell you that you can't,a `Stream` is an object which holds a load of bytes in memory. It doesn't store the location of where those bytes came from. The data inside a `Stream` could have come from a file, a web page, or any other source

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure the ImageSource is a stream, you can use a cast ImageSource to StreamImageSource, and then get the stream from that.

Example:

```
var imageStreamSource = (StreamImageSource)profilePicture.Source;
Stream actualStream = await imageStreamSource.Stream(new CancellationToken());
```